# Splash screen on Android is not working

Tags: android, cordova

I have an application on Cordova (6.2) and install it into Android device (Android v6.0). To change application icon I replace an icon in `/platforms/android/res/drawable-hdpi` and it works fine. But when I add

```
<platform name="android">
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="1000" />
</platform>
```

to config.xml and recompile an application - splash screen was not showing.

How to fix this problem? (all default screens are present in folders and they names `screen.png`)

Comment: have you gone through https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen ??

Comment: @Naitik Yes, splash screen cordova plugin works fine. But as in cordova documentation it is not required and cordova has built-in splash screen (which is work without problem in iOS). My question is about this built-in splash screen, which is not work on Android.

Comment: on official doc of cordova also mentioned that https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/index.html , you need to use plugin and made splash screen with given size.

Comment: @Naitik ok, when compile application for iOS, i only replace images here `\platforms\ios\MyApp\Images.xcassets\LaunchImage.launchimage\` and splash screen appear :) That is why i think - Android applications must have simular functionality. Сorrect me if it is not.

Comment: @Naitik for example here /platforms/android/res is an images (icons and splash screens). But if I replace splash image here, nothing happened.

Comment: ok let me give you proper answer.. give me 2 mins for write down answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first of all install plugin for splash screen with following command:

> cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-splashscreen

then in config.xml copy following:

**for Android:**

```
<platform name="android">

    <splash src="res/screen/android/splash-land-hdpi.png" density="land-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/android/splash-land-ldpi.png" density="land-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/android/splash-land-mdpi.png" density="land-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/android/splash-land-xhdpi.png" density="land-xhdpi"/>

    <splash src="res/screen/android/splash-port-hdpi.png" density="port-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/android/splash-port-ldpi.png" density="port-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/android/splash-port-mdpi.png" density="port-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/android/splash-port-xhdpi.png" density="port-xhdpi"/>
</platform>
```

**For IOS:**

```
<platform name="ios">
    <splash src="res/screen/ios/Default~iphone.png" width="320" height="480"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/ios/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" height="960"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" height="1024"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" height="2048"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" height="768"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048" height="1536"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" height="1136"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-667h.png" width="750" height="1334"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-736h.png" width="1242" height="2208"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-Landscape-736h.png" width="2208" height="1242"/>
</platform>
```

now made splash screen with above size. you can do with many ways:

1) http://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/icon-splashscreen.html

2) http://ticons.fokkezb.nl/

now put all generated files in `res/screen/{platform}` folder and double check with entry with config.xml

now again go to config.xml and add following:

```
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="true" />
 <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
```

above tags hide splash screen after `3 seconds`.

Ping me if you still faced problem.

Hope it will help.

Comment: I'am already install splash screen plugin and it works fine on Android. But i'am interest in why in iOS splash screen works without cordova-plugin-splashscreen installing, and in Android not.

Comment: in android will work but then you need to make java activity. In IOS what it will Lunch image which is set in assets for ios and **XCODE** make splash screen behind the scene with IOS native. in android there is drawable folder where all splash screen stored which android made internally with out splash screen plugin. Which is white or blank right now. so better make changes as i mentioned in answer and make thing working.

Comment: I am using the same but default cordova logo with grey background comes

Comment: Hi Manoj, Did you do same steps mentioned above?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SplashScreen extends Activity {
    private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 3000;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splashscreen);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this,GetStartedScreen.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
    }
}
```

Comment: SPLASH_TIME_OUT variable you want to add what time in milisecond.

Comment: in your splase screen activity

Comment: I'am novice i Cordova, but think that my problem solving without code modification

Comment: @Nirmit this question on cordova javascript. don't touch native code as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

The Splash Screen Won't appears After I have Updated My CLI to 6.5.0 and the Older Verison Of the Plugin doesn't support the latest One.
SO I Removed the Older One (***Cordova-plugin-splash screen 3.2.2 "Splash screen"***) and added the Latest One()

**To Remove the Plugin Use:**

`cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-splashscreen`

**To Add the Plugin Use:**

```
cordova plugin addcordova-plugin-splashscreen
```